# Minecraft Inventory Testing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can i test for a item with a Color, or bold, etc Name in Players inventory? Ist work only with names without Color, but I want Color/bold items to test.

Comment: Which game are you playing, MCJava, MCBE, MCCE, …? The answer depends on that (and you're supposed to state that anyway, see tag wiki of [tag:minecraft-commands]).

Comment: Java Edition (Pc)

Comment: OK, then the existing answer is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
/execute if entity @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:stick",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"someText","color":"blue","bold":"true"}'}}}]}] run say hi
```

Also, The item name can be defined in multiple formats. You have to use the same format in both your generation and detection commands. Here's an example of some formats:

- Name: '"someText"'
- Name:"\"someText\""
- Name:'{"text":"someText"}'
- Name:"{\"text\":\"someText\"}"

Comment: Can you send me the command for this item: Italic: false, bold: true, Color: Gold, item:golden_pickaxe,name:"a" thx

Comment: @Hanz You can use the same command and just adjust the things you want to check for accordingly.

Comment: It doesnt work…, can you send me pls?